# Upgrade to 2.3.2 - unable to change the slider to No to unselect components

Tags: magento2, upgrade

During upgrade 2.3.1 to 2.3.2 I'm unable to unselect components using sliders. See screenshot. They just do not move

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Magento bug [confirmed](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/23445). (and will never be fixed)